# Unexpected use of comma operator no-sequences

Tags: typescript

My code is as follows:

```ts
const defaultKeys = ["a", "b", "c"];

const defaultKeysObj = defaultKeys.reduce(
        (acc: { [key: string]: number }, curr) => {
          return (acc[curr] = 0), acc;
        },
        {}
   );
```

What I'm trying to achieve is basically an object as such: `{a: 0, b: 0, c: 0}` but I'm getting an error of unexpected use of comma operator. How can I modify my `reduce` function?

Comment: This syntax is typescript, not javascript `acc: { [key: string]: number }`. If you're not using Typescript, try removing the type annotation, replace `acc: { [key: string]: number }` with just `acc`. And try writing out code instead of copying/pasting it, to help you understand it.

Comment: @AndyRay Yes I'm using typescript.

Comment: If you get an error, remember to [show that error in your post](/help/how-to-ask) (and not redacted or paraphrased, show the actual error text you get)

Comment: Maybe don't stuff that code on one line. Have `acc[curr] = 0` on one line, and `return acc` on the next. Or just use a loop: `const out = {}; for (const el of defaultKeys) { out[el] = 0; }`.

Comment: you can't return like this `return (acc[curr] = 0), acc;` its syntactically incorrect

Comment: @JSEvgeny it does work (non-TS mind) but it's just not very readable.

Comment: Oh might be, sorry, but not in typescript though. Although looking at it now, it could actually make sense in some other language.

Answer (score 0):

This should work the way you expect:

```
const defaultKeysObj = defaultKeys.reduce<{ [key: string]: number }>(
    (acc, curr) => ({...acc, [curr]: 0}),
    {}
);
```

You give return type in triangles, so called "generics", <{ [key: string]: number }> the type your returned result should be. And after each iteration you want to include all the previous values in the final result with spreading operator `...acc` and also include current value, so the object you want to return after each iteration is `{...acc, [curr]: 0}`

Comment: this is fancy but it create new object at every index that lead to bad performance.
check in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcZbY-Q0TIE)

Comment: I don't think this "performance" argument should prevent us from utilising modern syntax standards, we are not working on linux kernel here it's just JS and we iterate over 3 items :D Even if it would be a thousand or even more, performance would not be an issue

Answer (score 0):

When you use `return (acc[curr] = 0), acc;`.
You can not returning own initialValue object so that accumulator  is corrupted in second case. use console.log to view your accumulator

```
const defaultKeys = ["a", "b", "c"];
const obj = defaultKeys.reduce(
(acc, crr) => {
    acc[crr] = 0;
    return acc;
},

{}
);

console.log(obj);
```

Other way:

```
const defaultKeys = ["a", "b", "c"];
const keyMap = new Map();
for (const key of defaultKeys) keyMap.set(key, 0);

const obj = Object.fromEntries(keyMap);
console.log(obj);
```